# How do I get the Infix out of a sentence?

Tags: java

I am developing a program that asks the user for a word / letter. In this example i will type 'a'. The program will then see if 'a' is a prefix,suffix or infix of the word. I quickly figured out how to figure out the prefix and suffix using "startsWith(String s).

However, I wonder how I will be able to see the infix of the String s. The infix in hat is 'a' but how can I make my program figure that out?

So my question is:

*How will my program be able to tell if 'a' is an infix of "hat"?*

Is there some sort of algorithm or method I should use? I am really stuck here.

**I don't have any code due to the fact that I don't know how to face this problem.**

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please don't use tags randomly. If you read what [tag:infix-notation] says, it has nothing  to do with your question. That said... [`contains`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#contains(java.lang.CharSequence)).

Comment: @Amadan Oh, I didn't see that it auto corrected that. I wrote infix and it must have auto corrected it to infix-notation. Sorry!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`indexOf(String str)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#indexOf-java.lang.String-):

```
String word = "hat";
String letter = "a";

int index = word.indexOf(letter);
if (index == -1) {
    System.out.println("Not found");
} else if (index == 0) {
    System.out.println("Prefix");
} else if (index == word.length() - letter.length()) {
    System.out.println("Suffix");
} else {
    System.out.println("Infix");
}
```

Comment: So if the sentence is: "hatat" and I use the word / letter 'a' it will find 2 infixes?

Comment: @LiamAndersson Link to `indexOf` documentation has been fixed. The method finds the first occurrence of the search text, i.e. it would return `1` when calling `"hatat".indexOf("a")`. You can then call `"hatat".indexOf("a", 2)` to continue the search and get 3 back. A third call with `"hatat".indexOf("a", 4)` would return -1 (not found).

Comment: @Gokul It's a simple search of small string in larger string, so the size of the words doesn't matter.

Answer (score 2):

According to many sites on definition of Infix, it is an affix inserted inside a word stem.

I can tell to have dictionary of whole english words( it'll be having only formal words, and infix words are informal ), and compare with given word.

For comparison, use the longest letter match with score and take the highest score (some tuning might be required ) because it will be comparing against huge set of words.

But if you just ask a word on middle, just check if its neither prefix nor suffix. This won't work for all cases.

https://www.thoughtco.com/infix-words-and-grammar-1691167

Comment: I am just looking if the word exists in the sentence, I thought it was much more complicated than just doing like Andreas showed above...

Comment: Can you give 2-3 examples of infix?

Comment: Well, in got the infix is 'o' apparently, and 'a' is the infix of "hat" etc..

Comment: the word "bloody" is the infix of "fanbloodytastic"

Comment: Good. So dictionary words will have fantastic right, it checks and finds the anomaly. The trick is comparison algorithm. Updated answer for that